# __init__ arguments in Python/Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to call an **init** method, and it's parents in a function.  I'm probably doing something obviously dumb, but I can't figure it out.  I get an error when I have this code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics import Color

class FieldCommand(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FieldCommand, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.myBoard = Board(col=2, rows=2)
        for c in range(4):
            self.add_widget(Button(text = c))

class Board(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Board, self).__init__(**kwargs)



class FieldCommandApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return FieldCommand()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    FieldCommandApp().run()
```

Specifically, my error reads:

```
File "/Users/.../PycharmProjects/FieldCommand/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 350, in __init__
     super(Widget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 243, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.__init__
 TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize
```

)
I was following the example [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/examples/gen__demo__kivycatalog__main__py.html):

```
class Container(BoxLayout):


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Container, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.previous_text = open(self.kv_file).read()
        parser = Parser(content=self.previous_text)
        widget = Factory.get(parser.root.name)()
        Builder._apply_rule(widget, parser.root, parser.root)
        self.add_widget(widget)
```

Why is my application getting an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call to `self.myBoard = Board(col=2, rows=2)` includes `kwargs` for `col` and `rows` that are passed to the `Widget` `__init__()`, which does not accept those kwargs. So the fix is to extract those `kwargs` in your `Board` class. You can do that by simply adding `Properties` in your `Board` class like this:

```
class Board(Widget):
    # default values for `row` and `cols`
    col = NumericProperty(1)
    rows = NumericProperty(1)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Board, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks - there were several issues with my code above - I just think that I went passed my point of fatigue last night.  But your answer definitely put me on the right path.